# Using the video cam and open it to the public and ask for the correction of pronunciation etc

Tags: feature-request

This is just a proposal/my personal idea that if students are confident enough to show their faces in public such as

[**[**My shameless video**](https://youtu.be/d5R30w2Wupw)**]

couldn't it possibly be a good idea? (Were you able to understand what I was saying in the video?}

This is originally intended to make my youtube video but I thought it might work here too.

Or was this a direct aggravation to the idea of ELL community so may be I should delete this?

*My original intention was to make some Japanese history youtube because many people in the western countries are so interested in our culture (such as Samurais') but I found it it was too far fetched. Got to improve English skill ever harder.

Thank you for any opinion.

P.S Only what I found out was how fat I am. I got to go to gym asap.

P.S 2 Do I look like just an idiot?

Comment: Yeah! The more I look at mine, the more an asshole what I am! My ugly face!. I'll go on a diet from today.

Comment: I applaud you going out on a limb. Based on this video I would recommend you work on your /l/ and /r/ (it's actually [ɹ], commonly know as "the 'R' sound"). Try a very exaggerated /l/ and doing it consistently might help.

Comment: @EddieKal I'm already 46 years old so who cares my visual. Thank you for the correction. As you well know, since I am a Japanese and the language doesn't distinguish between R sound and L sound so I myself too noticed I couldn't hear what I was saying and what you pointed out became too obvious. But thank you again. It's like just what is started as a sub-fun-tube became to the long way to Rome before even it reaches.

Comment: @EddieKal I am afraid I might do the "risky things" within a few days. (Here in Meta). Kindly be notified that if you **that** is not the business of even Meta, please delete it right away when spot it. Sorry.

Comment: Before I answer,  have you considered any apps that already exist? I googled "video chat to learn pronunciation" and found a few that looked like they might be quite helpful. And some are even mobile friendly.

Comment: @GWarner Thank you for the info. It sounds good in a way, but how would it be "robotic"? As I asked in another question, I rather hire a private tutor since they are more flexible. But thank you for the info and kindly provide me with the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search "video chat to learn pronunciation", there are a few Youtube channels with videos for specific words done by tutors. One I looked at mentions classes, so that sounds like a tutor to consider. In the Google search a few app suggestions came up such as fluentu.com and hellotalk.com.

As far as trying to do what you suggested on Stack Exchange would be unwise because we are all volunteers with our own regional dialects and accents and that could be too influential and possibly incorrect.