# Can I recruit a spot paid type private teacher here?

Tags: support, scope

So, I am the guy who broadcast myself "virtually" [**in this question (proposal)**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/using-the-video-cam-and-open-it-to-the-public-and-ask-for-the-correction-of-pron)

And as I said in the question, I have a some kind of hobby like YouTubing project for educating myself and those who are interested in my country (in English BTW).

Yes, sure there are many recruiting sites in my country too, so you might ask me "Why here"?

The current merit to me is:

1. I'm doing FX trading except for when I'm working or when I need to meet some people. (Therefore I'm relatively often inside home.)
2. I like ELL and I always take a look at it at least a peek a day.
3. On Sundays and Saturdays, I mostly read books (for that YouTube thing)

In short, I just happened to be here searching for a teacher.

But Stack Exchange is not that kind of site, so is it OK? If not, I will delete this. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I can do it. Can you go to the chat room on ELL? I will create a room for you and me, and then we can talk about it. OK? I will delete this in five minutes.

Comment: @Lambie Did you decide to stop to be my XXX? Was it because the wage is not good? Or since I can not enter the chat room "if you really get a ban at another site, you can "enter", but can not post anything", you thought I am kinda spammer? ( which is I am not ). Anyway, thanks.

Comment: KENTARO, LISTEN TO ME. I will help you. Tell me why you cannot go into a chat room on ELL. Are you sure of that? Please try to explain what you are trying to say to me very simply.

Comment: @Lambie or I'm asking at Meta link [ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354895/could-you-teach-me-when-i-got-a-ban-at-another-site-why-cant-i-enter-the-chat?noredirect=1#comment1185791_354895 ]

Comment: @Lambie, Meta has an answer. Kindly see it. There is nothing I can do anymore. If you would like to have "it" with me, the only way is you must believe me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Stack Exchange Q&A isn't the place for recruiting people. Stack Overflow has a special section called [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) for these kind of things, but that's limited to positions in IT (and you have to pay if you're recruiting).